# 3D effects like HTC One Dimension plus

Tags: image-processing

Its true that HTC one M8 uses dual camera to achieve the 3D Dimension plus effect, but can anybody tell what is it called, if its a series of image manipulation?

Demonstrated here, 
[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PuKphXzWwII)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_data_acquisition_and_object_reconstruction

Answer (score 1):

The technique demonstrated in the video appears to be "image morphing" which is not specific to 3D.  They have "morphed" a left-eye view to a right-eye view and back.  The resulting animation is a form of "wiggle" stereoscopic presentation.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphing

Here's an example I just made from an old stereo pair
of a Civil War cannon, from the Library of Congress.  I used
ImageMagick's "-morph" option to rock back and forth between
the two images:

http://www.simplesystems.org:/users/glennrp/stereo/loc_cannon.gif

See also the "wiggle method" of stereoscopy, with some more examples,
at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiggle_stereoscopy
This method typically just alternates between the left and right images, but sometimes "morphing" or filling in with intermediate photos are used.